# SVG filter quality when used as CSS background

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-filters

I am trying to use a SVG file as a background for a div and everything is working just fine except when I add a filter to the SVG file it displays very rough. Is there some sort of setting that I need to add in the CSS or inside the SVG file to increase the quality? 
   I have a web application that has a bunch of icons and was trying to lighten up the site by loading one file and offsetting the backgrounds but still keeping the quality high and having the icons scalable. Am I going about this the wrong way?

I am using Inkscape to generate the SVG file

Here is my CSS:

```
.icoErase{
   width: 1em;
   height: 1em;
   background-image: url('../images/FormIcons.svg');
   background-size: auto 6em;
   background-position: -1em -1em;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: What does your markup look like?

Comment: What do you mean by 'add a filter' to the SVG?

Comment: For example a Shadow that would contain a Gaussian Blur... It is showing up very pixleated

Comment: I mean, do you use a software like photoshop to do so? If so, I doubt what you get after is an SVG. SVG is vector based, so it scales and doesnt become pixelated. If you apply a filter it might change the image format, and it no longer scales

Comment: Where's your filter?

Comment: Inside of the SVG file I will try to extract part of the file and post it

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest setting an explicit filterRes attribute on the filter element within your SVG of anywhere from 1000 to 2000. Browsers sometimes pick incorrect default settings.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox no longer support filteRes as its deprecated in the filter effects spec and really complicated to implement once you have multiple filters on a single element.

Comment: Even when you specify SVG 1.1?

Comment: Even then, all UAs ignore the version attribute.